# Linear programming constraint specification

Tags: linear-programming

How do you specify a linear constraint to an integer program where, given a binary variable x over a period of t intervals (x1,x2…xt), you want x to be =1 either never or at least n consecutive times?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It depends on the whole model which constraint satisfy the condition. A condition alone is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the topic of your question since your problem is formulated using binary/integer variables (it is not a linear programming problem).

Given that $n \le t$, we can define auxiliary binary variable $y_j \in \{0,1\}$ for each $j \in \{1,\dots,t-n+1\}$ which takes value one if **at least** $n$ variables $x_j,\dots,x_{n+j-1}$ take value one. If we want either none or **exactly** $n$ consecutive variables to take value one then we can add the following constraints to our model:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=j}^{n+j-1} x_i \ge ny_j\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall j \in \{1,\dots,t-n+1\}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{t} x_i \le n\\
&\sum_{j=1}^{t-n+1} y_j \le 1 
\end{align}

Let $z_k \in \{0,1\}$ be an auxiliary binary variable which takes value one if **exactly** $k \in \{n,\dots, t\}$ consecutive $x$ variables take value one. If we want none or **at least** $n$ consecutive variables to take value one, then it is enough to add the following constraint to the model:

\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=j}^{k+j-1} x_i \ge k(y_j+z_k-1)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall k \in \{n,\dots, t\}, \ \forall \, j \in \{1,\dots,t-k+1\}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{t} x_i \le \sum_{k=n}^{t} kz_k\\
&\sum_{k=n}^{t} z_k \le 1
\end{align}

Note that there may be several other ways to formulate your problem.